# Change position of a line with a specific string, using python

Tags: python, string, attributes

I am new to coding, trying to find a simple python code for re-arranging some lines. Lines have specific string to select. Those lines with this specific string need to be moved.

Original File content:

```
element = element1
attribute1 = value1last
attribute2 = value2
attribute3 = value3

element =element2
attribute1 = value1last
attribute2 = value2
attribute3 = value3
```

Note: the attribute line with "last" in it, this whole line should go to the end of each element's attribute list.

New file format:

```
element = element1
attribute2 = value2
attribute3 = value3
attribute1 = value1last

element =element2
attribute2 = value2
attribute3 = value3
attribute1 = value1last
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? any research or ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: I havent been able to do it yet. @Rabinzel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
#print(data)

sep_lists = [[]]
for i in data:
    if not i:
        sep_lists.append([])
    else:
        sep_lists[-1].append(i)

#print(sep_lists)
for lists in sep_lists:
    for idx, elem in enumerate(lists):
        if 'last' in elem:
            last = idx
    lists.append(lists.pop(last))

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lists in sep_lists:
        f.write('\n'.join(lists) + '\n\n')
```

Comment: That worked.. This saves a lot of hours. Thanks